# Python: Entry Window sometimes will not die

Tags: python, gtk

I have this odd intermittent problem with a popup dialog that requests the user to enter a URL and press enter. Roughly half of the time, there is no response to the user pressing Enter. It can happen twice in a row for the same entered data and then work the third time with the same input. Restarting the application doesn't really alter much with the behaviour. I'm trying to debug it with breakpoints and watches using PyCharm but I can't get it to step into the functions properly.

The two functions which manage the user input are as follows:

```
def on_click_pic(self, button, null):
    self.url_win = Gtk.Window()
    self.url_win.set_default_size(500,20)
    self.url_win.set_border_width(10)
    self.url_win.set_title("Enter a URL for the player photo")
    self.url_win.add(self.url_entry)
    self.url_win.show_all()

def on_url_enter(self, event):
    search = self.url_entry.get_text()
    self.url_win.destroy()
    print "getting image: %s " % search
    self.get_image(search, self.e_image)
    self.e_pic = search
    print "e_pic set to %s" % search
```

The first function is triggered when the user clicks on a GTKImage pinned to an Event Box. This part always works. The second one is activated by the connect of the entry box which is called in the main by

```
self.url_entry.connect("activate", self.on_url_enter)
```

It's as though this connect function is only called about half the time as on_url_enter does not appear to run the rest of the time. I've tried checking my steps to see does the entry box lose focus but there's no patter to it. Is there anything else I should be looking for or is there a more reliable way to code this, maybe by making a modal class of the entry box?

Comment: Can you provide a *working minimal* example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'll give it a go. I'll have to rewrite all the database access bits first so it runs on a basic dataset.

Comment: The problem sounds as if it should be reproducible without a database.

Comment: This should work: http://pastebin.com/F60uJPB7
When it starts, clicking in the blank area to the right of First Name and above Suspended Until will pop up the box for entering the URL.

Comment: Although this is not quite as minimal as I thought, I tried it various times and the box always disappeared when I hit enter.

Comment: I think I can see the reason but not the solution now - If you copy and paste a URL into the box and then edit it and hit Enter that does nothing. Also, from that point on, even if you close the entry box and reopen it, no input will be accepted until the application is restarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you defined `self.url_entry = Gtk.Entry()` in your __init__ method. This caused the behaviour you described. You can just use:

```
def on_click_pic(self, button, event):
    self.url_win = Gtk.Window()
    self.url_win.set_default_size(500,20)
    self.url_win.set_border_width(10)
    self.url_win.set_title("Enter a URL for the player photo")
    url_entry = Gtk.Entry()  # define your GtkEntry here
    url_entry.connect('activate', self.on_url_enter)
    self.url_win.add(url_entry)
    self.url_win.show_all()

def on_url_enter(self, url_entry):
    search = url_entry.get_text()
    self.url_win.destroy()
    print "getting image: %s " % search
    self.get_image(search, self.e_image)
    self.e_pic = search
    print "e_pic set to %s" % search
```

Comment: well that seems to work a treat. cheers! I'm still trying to grasp why that causes this behaviour specifically if the input text is edited before pressing enter